# Does org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(Reader reader) method preserves the order of elements and attributes of XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax, dom4j

**My XML file is:**

```
<XYZ>
    <A name="one">
        <label>I am A one</label>
    </A>
    <B name="two">
        <label>I am B two</label>
    </B>
    <A name="three">
        <label>I am A three</label>
    </A>
</XYZ>
```

**My Code is:**

```
String myXmlAsString = //Read the above xml as String
Document document = new SAXReader().read(new StringReader(myXmlAsString ));
List<Element> dataElements = document.selectNodes("/XYZ");
```

**My Question is:**

If I read my XML file through above mentioned code then does the `dataElements` List returned by `selectNodes(String xPathExpr)` method will have the same order as in the original XML file?

If yes, does this holds true even if the XML has deep nesting and I call the `selectNodes(String xPathExpr)` method on any `Element` object from this document object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath does not change the order of elements when returning results, so the elements are exactly in the same order as in your input xml.

Comment: Thanks @tfoo for the answer, Also can I be sure that my `document` object will have the same sequence as that of the XML file always?

Answer (score 1):

Lists are ordered structures. There is no reason for the SAXReader to remove that order.